# How to create tables with specific behavior

Tags: sql, sqlite

Basically what I want to do is to:

1. Create table `ADDITION` with columns (`character`, `description`).
2. Create table `THING` with columns (`id`, `name`, `addition`).
3. Allow only adding items into `THING` if addition value is present in `ADDITION` table.
   3.1. Very important - there should be the possibility to append one, many or none of those values.
4. In Python I would like to check the `addition` column from the `THING` table and do specific things regarding column to content.
   4.1. How to implement addition? FOREIGN KEY allows content only exactly the same as the character column from the `ADDITION` table - but I want to allow many characters.

Example:

1. `create table ADDITION  (character char unique not null primary key, description text not null)`
2. `create table THING (id integer not null primary key, name text not null, addition text reference ADDITION (character))`

In this case I can only have:

ADDITION table content:

```
(a,"something"), (b, "something") ...
```

THING table content:

```
(1, "apple", "a"), (2, "angle grinder", "b")
```

but I would like to have

```
(1, "apple", ""), (2, "angle grinder", "ab"), (3, "cola", "agu")
```

and it is impossible due to foreign key.

And one more thing - is the any SQL method to add character `b` into (3, "cola", "agu") or is the only way to check if it's there in Python (or Java etc) code and append if its not there?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a more normal form, and use numbers instead of letters, then use keys:

```
create table addition
(
  add_id integer primary key,
  add_desc text
);

create table thing
(
  th_id integer primary key,
  th_desc text
);

create table thing_addition
(
  th_id integer,
  add_id integer,
  foreign key (th_id) references thing(th_id),
  foreign key (add_id) references addition(add_id)
);
```

Using letters in your intended method limits you to a set number of entries